# Getting additional information <div> using PHP web-scraping

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data from a website. I am relatively new to this so I am open to any suggestions. I have looked at several stackoverflow posts but can't find a similar problem/solution.

First, I use DOM to find all the div's in the page (here https://stackoverflow.com/ given as an example). Then I can easily get any information contained in 'class=' or 'id='. However, this page uses some additional, non-standard tags containing links. I would like to scrape this link information. For example:

```
<div class="made-up-class" additional-link="https://www.google.com/">
```

Ideally I would get all the information from the additional link.

My code so far is, which doesn't work:

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://stackoverflow.com/');

foreach($html->find('div') as $element)
        $element->find('additional-link');
                echo $element;
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say your code so far doesn't work. What exactly do you see when you run it? That might be useful information to add to your question.

Comment: you should look for simple_html_parser docs to see how to get xml element with specified attributes

Comment: With your `find("additional-link")` you're not accessing a property but searching for a further child

Answer (score 0):

First thing first. For multi line loops curly brackets are a must, check [PSR-2 standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) .

So, in your example, first do this:

```
    foreach($html->find('div') as $element) {
       $element->find('additional-link');
       echo $element; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you can scrape the value of `additional-link` complying the following approach. I showed how you can parse a single element. Given that you can always create a loop to get them all.

```
<?php
    require('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = "https://stackoverflow.com/";

    $htmldoc = file_get_html($html);
    $item = $htmldoc->find('[class="made-up-class"]',0);
    echo $item->getAttribute("additional-link");
?>
```